# Django query unsupported format character '"' (0x22)

Tags: python, django, string, sqlite

I'm passing a store_id field from a link on my index page to the view in order to look it up and provide a show store page. I'm using a sqlite backend but the Model.objcts.get() function won't return the object. It throws this error pointing at my .get line:

```
ValueError at /store/1001946/
unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 192
Request Method: GET
```

My views .py

```
def store(request, store_id):
   print(type(store_id))
   sto = StoreStat.objects.get(storeid=store_id)
   return render(request, 'stores/store.html', {'store': sto})
```

I've tried changing the type to an integer, played with encoding, but nothing seems to work. I also tried .filter() because its similar but I get the same error

My app urls

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('store/<store_id>/',views.store, name='store')
]
```

project urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
  path('', include('stores.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

index.html

```
<ol>
      {% for store in top %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'store' store_id=store.storeid%}">{{ 
               store.storestorename }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
 </ol>
```

Comment: Can you show the (relevant) `urlpatterns`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure

Comment: Can you show all the logs?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error. One of my fields in my database included a % symbol. 
I had to go back and rename the column without it and it worked.
I guess this threw the whole thing off!